# How to access members of another class in a different file

Tags: ruby, rake

I'm using [ruby-prolog](https://github.com/preston/ruby-prolog).  I want to run a task to query a fact.

demo.rb:

```
require 'ruby-prolog'

c = RubyProlog::Core.new
c.instance_eval do

person['name','brian'].fact
person['name','James'].fact

puts 'all the names are: '
p query(person['name', :A])

end
```

This works great.  Now I want to run the query inside of Rake.  That is a problem because I don't know how to access `person[]` from the other file.

Rakefile.rb:

```
require_relative 'demo.rb'

task :test do |variable|
  puts 'all the names are: '
  p query(person['name', :A])
end
```

Error:

> all the names are:  rake aborted! NameError: undefined local variable
>   or method `person' for main:Object

I'm hoping this can be solved by passing an object back somehow.  I tried accessing `c`, but it did not work out.  Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't the code need to be a block for a `RubyProlog::Core` instance, as it is in the working case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your demo file, both variables `person` and `c` are local variables and will not be accessible from outside of that context. If you require `demo.rb` into an irb session, the behavior should be the same; neither `c` nor `person` will be defined.

A good way of dealing with this in rake tasks is to keep any and all logic out of the rake task itself, and only call out to another object that takes care of the task. For a quick and dirty example, you could alter your code as such:

```
# demo.rb
require 'ruby-prolog'

class Demo
  def self.run_demo
    # Existing code:

    c = RubyProlog::Core.new
    c.instance_eval do

      person['name','brian'].fact
      person['name','James'].fact

      puts 'all the names are: '
      p query(person['name', :A])

    end
  end
end
```

and

```
# Rakefile.rb
require_relative 'demo.rb'

task :test do
  Demo.run_demo
end
```

Comment: I'm looking to split my facts from my queries.  This does not get me all the way there, but OO is a good start.  I can work on a way to divide this out a little more.  Ruby properties seem a little too verbose for making the properties members.  I'll look around to see if I can make facts into private fields.

Comment: The issue here was only to do with Ruby local variables and contexts; the implementation of queries and facts didn't make a difference.

Another (worse) way that the issue could have been resolved is instead of using local variables in your `demo.rb` file, `c` and `person` could have been made instance variables (`@c` and `@person`). They would then be like instance variables for the Ruby environment, and accessible from both files.